# Time stamp not outputting the date correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a time stamp field called sbuscriptionexpires in my mysql database. I have it set in my session

```
Array (
  [userid] => 6
  [ufname] => Kamal 
  [ulname] => Roberts 
  [uemail] => dbs@gmail.com
  [phone] => 5148036843 
  [otherdetails] => 
  [isactive] => yes 
  [memid] => 1 
  [memdate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 
  [sbuscriptionexpires] => 2018-02-28 00:00:00 
  [userprofilepic] => 
)
```

But When I go to echo out the date it just shows as blank

```
<p>Subscription Expires: 
  <?php echo date('m/d/Y', usbuscriptionexpires); ?>
</p>
```

It should be printing out

```
2018-02-28
```

Comment: In your code, `usbuscriptionexpires` is an undefined constant. Missing `$` ?

Comment: @Syscall I should have mentioned i store it in that on the session which is gettinfg filled in as you see the arrray above

Comment: @DavidB How you populate the variable is somewhat irrelevant to this issue - you still have to refer to variables with a $ at the start of them. To be clear: change it to `echo date('m/d/Y', $usbuscriptionexpires);` . It's just a typo, or a misunderstanding of PHP syntax.

Comment: Like @Syscall said, `echo date('m/d/Y', $usbuscriptionexpires);`  you need that `$` to indicate a variable name

Answer (score 2):

Try `strtotime()`:

```
 <p>Subscription Expires: 
 <?php 
      echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($usbuscriptionexpires));
 ?>
 </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>Subscription Expires: 
<?php 
echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($usbuscriptionexpires));
?></p>
```